# Tsql Query to find the most repeating String answer from two columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have survey results which is conducted on different dates to same set of users and I want to find most repeated answer for each user.

This is how my data looks

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

P

Comment: Please provide table data structure and types, with data examples

Comment: Also provide the code you already wrote to attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Brad, I just created a table to give column names and datatypes            
 Create Table Survey(
  UserId Varchar(15),
  AnswerDate date,
  Form1 varchar(15),
  Form2 varchar(15)
)                                                                                                                         and click on the link "Before" and "after" to look at the data

Comment: Before asking question, learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And if two values are tied for top for a given user, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: When two results are tie, then show both of them

Answer (score 1):

*For Microsoft SQL Server*

1. Get columns separately with count of unique values
2. Order the data set by the sum broken up per user (partition by)
3. Only keep the top-most record per user (row 1)

Code:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (UserId TINYINT, Form1 NVARCHAR(20), Form2 NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 1, 'Y', 'Y';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 1, 'Y', 'Y';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 1, 'D', 'Y';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 1, 'D', 'D';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 1, 'C', 'Y';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 2, 'D', 'Y';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 2, 'D', 'Y';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 2, 'D', 'Y';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 2, 'D', 'D';
INSERT @tbl (UserId,Form1,Form2) SELECT 2, 'C', 'Y';

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
          UserId,[String],SUM(Cnt) AS [SumCnt]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY SUM(Cnt) DESC) AS [Row]
    FROM (
        SELECT UserId,Form1 AS [String],COUNT(Form1) AS Cnt
        FROM @tbl
        GROUP BY UserId,Form1
        UNION
        SELECT UserId,Form2,COUNT(Form2) AS Cnt
        FROM @tbl
        GROUP BY UserId,Form2
    ) col
    GROUP BY UserId,[String]
) ord
WHERE ord.[Row]=1
```

Comment: Step #3 is not considering userid #2 has two most common answers, not a single one.

Comment: @TheImpaler Good catch, but I don't see how OP wants to explicitly handle ties for a given user.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
select dv.*
from (select d.userid, v.ans, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by d.userid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from mydata d cross apply
           (values (form_1), (form_2)) v(ans)
      group by d.userid, v.ans
     ) dv
where seqnum = 1;
```

I think the above is easier to understand, but you can write this without the subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties d.userid, v.ans, count(*) as cnt
from mydata d cross apply
     (values (form_1), (form_2)) v(ans)
group by d.userid, v.ans
order by row_number() over (partition by d.userid order by count(*) desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
create table tab (userid int, form1 nvarchar, form2 nvarchar);
insert tab values (1, 'y', 'n');
insert tab values (1, 'y', 'n');
insert tab values (1, 'n', 'n');
insert tab values (1, 'n', 'n');
insert tab values (2, 'y', 'y');
insert tab values (2, 'y', 'y');
insert tab values (2, 'n', 'n');
insert tab values (2, 'n', 'n');
insert tab values (3, 'y', 'y');

with x as (
  select userid, form1 as resp, count(*) as cnt from tab group by userid, form1
  union all
  select userid, form2, count(*) as cnt from tab group by userid, form2
  ),
  y as (
  select userid, resp, sum(cnt) as totcnt
    from x
    group by userid, resp
  ),
  z as (
  select userid, max(totcnt) as maxcnt from y group by userid
  )
select z.*, y.resp from z
  join y on y.userid = z.userid and y.totcnt = z.maxcnt
```

Result:

```
userid       maxcnt       resp  
--------------------------------
1            6            n     
2            4            n     
2            4            y     
3            2            y
```

Please note it shows two "most common answers" for userid = 2, and that's correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked exactly according to my data

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this query:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (UserId INT, Form1 NVARCHAR, Form2 NVARCHAR)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1, 'Y', 'N')
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1, 'Y', 'N')
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1, 'N', 'N')
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1, 'N', 'N')
INSERT @tbl VALUES (2, 'Y', 'Y')
INSERT @tbl VALUES (2, 'Y', 'Y')
INSERT @tbl VALUES (2, 'N', 'N')
INSERT @tbl VALUES (2, 'N', 'N')
INSERT @tbl VALUES (3, 'Y', 'Y')

SELECT X.UserId, SUM(Total) AS 'Total' FROM (
    SELECT UserId, CASE WHEN Form1 = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Form2 = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Total' FROM @tbl
) X
GROUP BY X.UserId
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```